# Manifest XML not well-formed (invalid token) Android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

So, I think I accidentally deleted something from the manifest, but I am using AIDE and I no longer have the option to undo it. I've looked through examples on StackOverflow and throughout the general Internet, trying to find the problem with the manifest, but nothing seems to be missing. The error is showing after the android:label line in `<activity>`.

Before supposedly deleting something, the app compiled and ran as expected. Thanks to anyone that can help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bitcoin.app" >

        <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is the issue? Error log or some error message would help.

Comment: It is "aapt: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)" after application's androind:label>

Comment: can you post your strings.xml?

Comment: Did any comments or answers helped, or you solved it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a compilation error in your XML file, something that shouldn't be there: a spelling mistake/a spurious character/an incorrect namespace.

Check your `@string` file and `XML file.`

**Eg:** `android:text="@string/hello";`

> a semicolon that shouldn't be there after this line